# Save multiple images to database using IFormFile asp.net core 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Images not saved in the database but it is shown when I debug the code why (.Add) object not working

```cs
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // there is Code here

    var imageList = new List<AdsImg>();
    foreach (IFormFile photoIform in userInfoModelView.Photo)
    {
        if (photoIform.Length > 0)
        {
            var stream = photoIform.OpenReadStream();
            var img = Image.FromStream(stream);
            img.ScaleAndCrop(273, 162)
            .SaveAs($"wwwroot\\upload\\{photoIform.FileName}");
            var img2 = new AdsImg
            {
                AdId = ad.Id,
                ImgPath = photoIform.FileName,

            };
            imageList.Add(img2);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you saving an image to a database? It looks like you are saving them to a file directory - `"wwwroot\\upload\\{photoIform.FileName}"`? Also, I don't think this namespace: `System.Drawing.Image` provides a `.SaveAs` method - (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Comment: In your example code, all you are doing is adding an image to a `List<T>`. I see no where in your example where you place it in a database. Also, are you using some kind of 3rd party software or something? I can't find either method `.ScaleAndCrop` or `.SaveAs` in the `System.Drawing.Image` class.

Comment: Thanks, I added _context.Add(img2) and it's working